# Deply ERC20 token to cross / multiple chains?

Tags: token, ethereum, polygon, erc20, binance-smart-chain

I have a new Erc20 token built on Polygon network and available on Polyscan, how can I make it available on Binance smart chain as well, the same way like other tokens??
example :The Floki Inu
https://blockscan.com/address/0x2B3F34e9D4b127797CE6244Ea341a83733ddd6E4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we deploy same ERC20-token on different blockchains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68802705/can-we-deploy-same-erc20-token-on-different-blockchains)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!

Multichain formerly known as Anyswap has a bridge allowing your token to exist on multiple chains.

Find the tutorial here:

[Multichain token](https://medium.com/multichainorg/apply-for-your-token-to-go-cross-chain-66f3d3af2dcc)

It is also possible if your token is already deployed on a (evm compatible) chain like polygon, bsc or ftm.
Also take a look at the official doc:

[Multichain doc](https://medium.com/multichainorg/apply-for-your-token-to-go-cross-chain-66f3d3af2dcc)