# contract address after deploying the smart contract is not matching with the address after running npx hardhat node

Tags: ethereum, solidity, hardhat

When i run npx hardhat node .....there are 20 different accounts

but when i run : npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network localhost
deployed address is not matching with any of those 20 accounts .....
what should i do now ??

i m expecting that deployed contract should match with any of those 20 accounts

after deploy : contract Address: 0x9fE467.............

after npx hardhat node :

Account #0: 0xf39Fd6.........
Account #1: 0x7099797........
Account #2: 0x3C44Cd .........

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
till 20 acouns but none of these matching to depployed contract address

Answer (score 0):

The 20 predefined addresses are EOAs - Externally Owned Addresses. Meaning each of them is derived from a private key. And in the case of Hardhat, these 20 private keys are derived from a [test mnemonic](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/config#hd-wallet-config) seed.

A smart contract address is not EOA. It's not derived from a private key. Instead, the contract address is derived from its deploying transaction. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68805158/1693192) for more info on how exactly is the contract address calculated depending on the `CREATE`/`CREATE2` opcodes).

Since the contract address is generated during its deployment, it's different from the pregenerated EOAs.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for the information....

Answer (score 0):

@Petra is correct, the 20 addresses are dummy accounts that you can use to interact with your contract.